# Can I tell if my peers enable mempoolfullrbf?

Tags: p2p, replace-by-fee, services

Trying to ensure my node is connected to some fullrbf peers, but it doesn't seem that there is a discoverable service for fullrbf? Am I stupid or missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitcoin Core pull request [#25600](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/25600) proposed advertising full-RBF on service bit 26 and connecting to four other full-RBF nodes. This was never merged, but some people use this patch on their nodes nevertheless. Peter Todd [maintains the patch](https://github.com/petertodd/bitcoin/tree/full-rbf-v26.0), and his [Libre Relay](https://github.com/petertodd/bitcoin/tree/libre-relay-v26.0) fork also has it, among other changes that relax the mempool policy.

However, enough people have probably enabled mempoolfullrbf that you might already be connected to full-RBF peers, especially if your node accepts incoming connections and thus has a lot of peers.